# Queries to group items with variants

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have this data:

```
"progress" "description" "quantity"
"1" "crodino"   "1"
"2" "bitter"    "1"
"3" "+ghiaccio" "1"
"4" "crodino"   "2"
"5" "bitter"    "1"
"6" "crodino"   "1"
"7" "bitter"    "1"
"8" "+limone"   "1"
"9" "-oliva"    "1"
"10" "bitter"   "1"
"1" "bitter"    "2"
```

The items without "+" or "-" in the first char are normal products, but the items with "+" or "-" are the variants (ex: +limone and - oliva are the variants of bitter, which have the progress number 7)

I need this result with a query:

```
"progress" "description" "quantity"
"1" "bitter" "4"
"2" "bitter" "1"
"3" "+limone" "1"
"4" "- oliva" "1"
"5" "bitter" "1"
"6" "+ghiaccio" "1"
"7" "crodino" "4"
```

This:

- First get the products with the variants in the next progress number and display it
- Alphabetically order the main product, then the variants in it.
- Group and sum the quantity in the other products

What is the query for doing it?

My db is sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

**I won! (but doesn't work in WebSQL in Chrome :( )**

```
select table1.progressivo,table1.desc,table1.qt from  comanda as table1 
inner join  comanda as table2
on table1.progressivo = (table2.progressivo -1)
and (substr(table1.desc,1,1)!='-' and substr(table1.desc,1,1)!='+')
and (substr(table2.desc,1,1)='+' or substr(table2.desc,1,1)='-') 

union 

select progressivo,desc as descrizione, qt from comanda where 
    (substr(desc,1,1)='+' or substr(desc,1,1)='-')  

    union

select table3.progressivo,table3.desc,sum(table3.qt) from  comanda as table3 
inner join  comanda as table4
on table3.progressivo = (table4.progressivo -1)
and (substr(table3.desc,1,1)!='-' and substr(table3.desc,1,1)!='+')
and (substr(table4.desc,1,1)!='+' or substr(table4.desc,1,1)!='-')  
    group by         table3.desc

order by progressivo asc ;
```

It was a casting problem.
I fixed doing this:

```
select table1.prog_inser,table1.desc_art,table1.quantita from  comanda as table1,comanda as table2
                    where table1.prog_inser =cast( cast(table2.prog_inser as int)-1 as varchar)
                    and table1.ntav_comanda='25' and table2.ntav_comanda='25'
                    and (substr(table1.desc_art,1,1)!='-' and substr(table1.desc_art,1,1)!='+')
                    and (substr(table2.desc_art,1,1)='+' or substr(table2.desc_art,1,1)='-')
                    union
                    select prog_inser,desc_art as descrizione, quantita from comanda where
                    (substr(desc_art,1,1)='+' or substr(desc_art,1,1)='-')
                    and ntav_comanda='25'
                    union
                    select table3.prog_inser,table3.desc_art,sum(table3.quantita) from  comanda as table3,comanda as table4
                    where table3.prog_inser =cast( cast(table4.prog_inser as int)-1 as varchar)
                    and table3.ntav_comanda='25' and table4.ntav_comanda='25'
                    and (substr(table3.desc_art,1,1)!='-' and substr(table3.desc_art,1,1)!='+')
                    and (substr(table4.desc_art,1,1)!='+' or substr(table4.desc_art,1,1)!='-')
                    group by table3.desc_art
                    order by prog_inser asc;
```